# Translate Zimbabwe to Chinese: 辛巴威 or 津巴布韦?

Tags: translation

Zimbabwe is a country. Which one is its Chinese translation: 辛巴威 or 津巴布韦?
Could it be possible that Chinese in Taiwan call it 辛巴威?

Another country is Zambia. 尚比亞 or 赞比亚?

Comment: Used Google map to verify that Taiwan people call them 辛巴威 and 尚比亞.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### tl;dr

Zimbabwe / Zambia is translated as:

- 津巴布韦 / 赞比亚 (for China, Malaysia & Singapore)
- 津巴布韋 / 贊比亞 (for Hong Kong & Macau)
- 辛巴威 / 尚比亞 (for Taiwan)

---

### In General

For such cases, my suggestion is:

1. Visit the **English** Wikipedia page of the topic ([Zimbabwe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zimbabwe), [Zambia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zambia))
2. Click 中文 under language to switch to **Chinese** Wikipedia
3. Choose the country specific page at the top of the page

   - 大陆简体 (Simplified Chinese, China)
   - 香港繁體 (Traditional Chinese, Hong Kong)
   - 澳門繁體 (Traditional Chinese, Macau)
   - 马新简体 (Simplified Chinese, Malaysia & Singapore)
   - 台灣正體 (Traditional Chinese, Taiwan)
4. Get the corresponding wordings

Answer (score 2):

In PRC we call them：津巴布韦 and 赞比亚